# Actively rendering a JComponent

Tags: java, swing

I am deploying a classic active-rendering graphical application in Java. In this setting, I am given a `Graphics2D g` component on which I can paint (e.g. boxes, text, shapes) using `g.draw...` operations.

Now, I want to re-use a Swing components, such as `JLabel`. Therefore, I would like to do something like `g.draw(new JLabel("Hello World!"));`. 
However, this primitive is not available for `Graphics2D` objects.

Do you know a workaround I could rely on, please?

Comment: You can use [SwingUtilities.paintComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#paintComponent-java.awt.Graphics-java.awt.Component-java.awt.Container-int-int-int-int-). However, if you just want to put the contents of a JLabel in your Graphics, you might be better off using [SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#layoutCompoundLabel-javax.swing.JComponent-java.awt.FontMetrics-java.lang.String-javax.swing.Icon-int-int-int-int-java.awt.Rectangle-java.awt.Rectangle-java.awt.Rectangle-int-).

Comment: Awesome! That worked perfectly. Thanks VGR!

Answer (score 1):

From VGR:
You can use `SwingUtilities.paintComponent`. However, if you just want to put the contents of a `JLabel` in your Graphics, you might be better off using `SwingUtilities.layoutCompoundLabel`.